# PHP Array with only unique values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am a beginner in coding and am trying to understand and adjust the below code to return only unique values without repetition from the database. I have tried different variations of unique_array() but without success unfortunately. How can I limit the values returned from the database to only unique ones?

```
<?php
$sql ="SELECT COUNT( status) AS total_building FROM add_bulding WHERE status=1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$total_building = $query->row_array();
?>

            <div class="b-list-section">                                   

                    <?php
                    if(!empty($building_info))
                    {   
                        foreach ($building_info as $value) 
                        {                       
                            $id = $value['id'];
                            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT building_id) AS total_list FROM add_listing WHERE  building_id='$id'";
                            $query = $this->db->query($sql);                                
                            $total_list = $query->row_array();

                        ?>
                            <a class="blink" target="_blank" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'details_building/' . $value['id'] ?>">
                                <div class="bilding-wrap">
                                    <h3 class="buildingtitle"><?php echo $value['title']; ?></h3>
                                      <?php if(!empty($value['image'])):?>
                                       <img class="bimage" src="<?php echo base_url("uploads/thumb/" . $value['image']); ?>"  alt="no image yet">
                                      <?php else:?>

                                      <?php $qry12=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_bulding_image WHERE add_building_id=$id");
                                         $sqr1=mysql_fetch_array($qry12);                        ?>                      
                                         <img class="bimage" src="<?php echo base_url("uploads/thumb/" . $sqr1['image']); ?>"  alt="no image yet">

                                         <?php endif;?>


                                </div> 
                            </a>
```

The above code returns listings that match what a user is searching for. Since 2 listings can be in the same building, the code is returning the same building twice.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: If you want unique results, why not `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @tadman I tried 'SELECT DISTINCT' but it didn't work - the code still returns repetitive results.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about the sorts of duplicates you're getting. It's not clear from your question what the problem is, so if you can edit it and include examples of result rows that would help.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you for the links, I will have to learn about this and look at how to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: @tadman added a description of the output to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(building_id) AS total_list FROM add_listing WHERE  building_id='$id' GROUP BY building_id
```

Comment: thanks tried this, it should work logically, but still getting repeated results displayed.

Comment: hmm i think not in query: try this if work i will edit my answer above. change foreach ($building_info as $value) into foreach (array_unique($building_info) as $value)